# Remove Option dynamically From select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select2

api return status which is assign to `$scope.status` it come dynamically

```
$scope.status = [{"planStatus":"Completed","records":2},{"planStatus":"Partial","records":22},{"planStatus":"Active","records":24},{"planStatus":"Merged","records":6}]
```

This is my html code where i created `select box` using ng-repeat

```
<select ng-options="sta.planStatus as sta.planStatus for sta in status" ng-model="plan.planStatus"  class="form-control">
         <option class="selectoption" value="">Select Status</option>
</select>
```

I am creating a `select box`, 5 option show in my select box
**I want to remove one option(like Active) from html?**    How can i do it. it is possible to do without change api response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular filters to remove the options. To remove the option where planStatus is 'Active', try this.

```
ng-options="sta.planStatus as sta.planStatus for sta in status | filter: optionsFilter"
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.optionsFilter = function (option) {
    if (option.planStatus == 'Active') {
        return false;
     }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this is show only Active Status not other but i want to remove it not show only it

Comment: No, this is to remove Active status option. Have you tried it?

Comment: yup thats why i said

Comment: Could you try this: filter: planStatus == 'Active'

Comment: its work but without write code in controller it can do, i can also do that but i want to it using html code